# how to do an OR on two words in a regular expression

Tags: regex

I want to write a regex that matches either:

```
insert #TempTable
```

or

```
update #TempTable
```

How do I do it? I guess an imperfect way to go about it would be:

```
[insertupda]{6} #TempTable
```

While this does work in my situation, i want to know the right way to do this.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
(insert|update) #TempTable
```

Comment: +1 for enlightening me on that syntax.  Whenever I have wanted to find one of two (or more) words in the same position I have resorted to `[iu][np][sd][ea][rt][te] #TempTable`, which, although not completely foolproof, works in the majority of situations.